# View in Android Studio to display all the unit tests of a project?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

I have tried the different views in Android Studio, and it seems I cannot view the tests available. I have to open each test file to look for the test inside.

Can't I display all the tests in my file or even better in all my test files, in one grouped view ? (as it is the case in Visual Studio)

Also is there a way to run some selectively ?

**EDIT**

Something like VS Test Explorer where tests are gathered from multiple files:

[image]

Comment: How do you want to select the tests? You can use annotations.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano please see my edit, I am looking for a view in the UI of Android Studio to do that